# graph of computed averages requires data in all cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010 and have created a spreadsheet that allows me to enter questionnaire responses from patients every week and display their average scores for each week on a line graph. Ideally, I would only have to enter any new data we get each week and the graphs would automatically populate. The problem is that my graphs are built to display the values from cells that contain an AVERAGE formula calculated from the individual questionnaire items. If there are no questionnaire items yet, the AVERAGE formula returns an error. If the formula returns an error, the graph displays this as a line dropping down to the X-axis. I want to be able to leave all necessary AVERAGE formulas in place in their cells and have the graphs reference all these AVERAGES for the 12-week program. I tried to solve this problem by using an IFERROR formula so that the cells with the AVERAGE formula would display as blank even if they returned an error. The IFERROR formula worked perfectly and the cell "looks" as though it is blank, but the graph still reads the fact that there is a formula in the cell and displays a dropping line. I have no idea if what I'm saying can even make sense to someone who isn't looking at my spreadsheet, but if it does and you know a solution, it would be wonderful. Thank you for reading my problem and for any help you may have to offer.

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of your spreadsheet data (If it is HIPAA bound, show us testing data then, or just numbers with zero context). Please also show us the exact relevant formulas.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the graph is showing empty cells as gaps. Next have your IFERROR return #N/A.

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(A1:A5),#N/A)`

This will give you blank spots in your graph if you are using a scatter plot, but a line graph will still connect between points:

[image: Chart]

Note that weeks 5,6,11,and 12 don't have data.

Comment: Brilliant!! It works! This will save me hours and make my spreadsheet usable by others! I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @Anne-Toh No problem, please mark the answer as accepted when you get a chance.